# Powershell Script to filter new Entra AD users

Tags: powershell, o365-flow, entra

I am trying to create a script to filter users recently created on Entra ID and set their usage location.

```
$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).Date
get-MsolUser -SearchString {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties whenCreated | Set-MsolUser -UsageLocation US
```

I am getting an error related to the parameter -Properties, as indicated below:

```
Get-MsolUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Properties'.
```

Can someone help me figuring out how to:
Search for users created up to a day ago and set their UsageLocation?

Thanks!

```
$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).Date
get-MsolUser -SearchString {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties whenCreated | Set-MsolUser -UsageLocation US
```

Comment: Did you actually read the error message? It's telling you that Get-MSOLUser doesn't have an argument called `Properties`. Take a look at the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0)

Comment: a quick look on google shows somebody using that and getting the `whenCreated` property by default, so you're probably safe to just remove `-Properties whenCreated` and go from there.

Comment: Any reason to use such an old module that will not work anymore soon